# How do I validate JSON using an existing schema file in Rust?

Tags: json, validation, rust

I'm trying to validate a JSON given a JSON file and a schema.

Schema:

```
{
    "Address":{
        "properties":{
            "City":{
                "type":"string"
            },
            "Country":{
                "type":"string"
            },
            "Street":{
                "type":"string"
            }
        },
        "type":"object"
    }
}
```

JSON:

```
{
    "Address":{
        "Street":"Downing Street 10",
        "City":"London",
        "Country":"Great Britain"
    }
}
```

My Rust file:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;
extern crate valico;

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;
use serde_json::Value;

use valico::json_dsl;
use valico::json_schema;

fn main() {
    let mut schemaFile = File::open("src/schema.json").unwrap();
    let mut jsonSchemaString = String::new();
    schemaFile.read_to_string(&mut jsonSchemaString).unwrap();

    let json_v4_schema: Value = serde_json::from_str(&jsonSchemaString).unwrap();


    let state = jsonSchemaString.process(&mut json_v4_schema, &None); //this is wrong as jsonSchemaString is not a jsonDsl.

    println!("Is valid: {}", state.is_valid())

}
```

I'm trying to use [valico](https://github.com/rustless/valico/blob/master/examples/example01.rs) for the JSON validation, but I cant figure out how to pass the schema against which the JSON has to be validated. I have seen examples where a `JsonDsl` is built using the valico builder, but how do I do it if I already have a JSON schema and I want to validate against that?  Is there any other way that I can achieve this?

Comment: Isn't this example what you want? https://github.com/rustless/valico#json-schema

Comment: `serialize::json;` is deprecated. I cant use it in a stable Rust

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Why is that relevant?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I think I see. (`serialize::json` is `use`d at the top of the sample.) The open issues (and how long they've been open) make me think this library might not get fixed: https://github.com/rustless/valico/issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Late to the party here, but in case [anyone](https://xkcd.com/979/) else is having trouble with this, below is a MVCE I've adjusted to using the schema and data you used as an example. I included the strings directly in the code for "simplicity", but you can just replace that with `fs::File`/`io::Read` operations you already had.

```
extern crate serde_json;
extern crate valico;

use serde_json::from_str;
use valico::json_schema;

fn main() {
    let s = from_str(r#"
    {
        "Address": {
            "Street":"Downing Street 10",
            "City":"London",
            "Country":"Great Britain"
        }
    }
    "#).unwrap();

    let j_schema = from_str(r#"
    {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "Address": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "Country": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "Street": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": ["Country", "Street"]
            }
        },
        "required": ["Address"]
    }
    "#).unwrap();

    let mut scope = json_schema::Scope::new();
    let r_schema = scope.compile_and_return(j_schema, true).ok().unwrap();

    println!("Is valid: {}", r_schema.validate(&s).is_valid())
}
```

Running this prints `Is valid: true`. Changing the "Address" to "Addresses" and running it again prints `Is valid: false`

Please note that I had to make some small adjustments to your schema. First, to verify that valico is validating it correctly I set required fields. Secondly, since the root object doesn't have a name (it's only `{}`) the "Address" would be a property of that root object.

So instead of

```
{
    "Address": {
        "properties": {
            ...
```

it is instead

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Address": {
            "type": "object",
                ....
```

Also, it seems like valico requires an older version of serde_json, so I added this as dependency in my Cargo.toml

```
serde_json = "0.8"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try this:

```
use valico::json_dsl;
use serde_json::{from_str, to_string_pretty}

...

let params = json_dsl::Builder::build(|params| {
    // code here
});

let mut obj = from_str(&jsonSchemaString).unwrap();

let state = params.process(&mut obj, &None);
```

Instead of using a type Value. This should work.

Comment: That's precisely my problem. I already have a JSON schema. I dont want to build a new schema to validate against.